# TypeError: undefined is not an object in WordPress API

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to access featured media source url but it shows me undefined, It works great on another url but not all

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]')

I tried both these

```
item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].source_url

tem._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url
```

API response

https://wp-sense.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed

Component

```
   <Text>
     {item._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url}
    </Text>
```

Comment: Can we see how `item` is getting defined?

Comment: doesnt show inside text not image, I edited the question